# How to check if WPS is enabled on a network using ESP32?

Tags: iot, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am working on a project using the ESP32 microcontroller and I need to check if WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup) is enabled on the network the ESP32 is trying to connect to. Is there any way to do this programmatically using the ESP32's built-in Wi-Fi library or any other libraries?

I have searched online for solutions, but most of them involve using external tools or scanning the network for WPS-enabled devices. However, I want to know if there is a way to check this information from the ESP32 itself.

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "I have searched online for solutions", well,  it tooks me a *search* of "WPS esp32" to find [this](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WPS). The code is also part of the examples that comes with Arduino ESP32 installed on Arduino IDE.

Comment: @hcheung Yup i found this, but this is about how to connect to a WPS router not how to scan if it has WPS on